# Custom price for a product

Tags: magento-1.9, price, event-observer, shopping-cart

I am developing a store in which you can buy a card at fixed price and can add any amount as per users wish.

So when product added to cart product price should be calculated in such a way that product price+amount choosen by customer. in addition to this other concepts are as same as magento default function like shipping mod charges, delivery charges etc..

To do this I am creating an observer event checkout_cart_product_add_after.

I created a module and calling checkout_cart_product_add_after event.

Below in my module config file

```
<config>
.
.
.
<global>
<events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <ucs_catalogorder_checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Ucs_CatalogOrder_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkoutCartProductAddAfter</method>
                </ucs_catalogorder_checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>

    </events>
</global>
</config>
```

and below is the Observer.php

```
<?php
class Ucs_CatalogOrder_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter($observer) {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();

        $walletAmount = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('card_wallet_amount');


        $item->setCustomPrice($walletAmount);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($walletAmount);
        $item->setCardWalletAmount($walletAmount);
        //$item->save();
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

        return $this;
    }
```

I have a custom field card_wallet_amount in my sales_flat_quote_item table, this field, custom_price and original_custom_price fields are getting updated with custom value, but total price is not updating based on the changes.

please suggest what goes wrong here.

As per my question database level, custom prices updating but on cart page, it is still showing only original product price.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem(); $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item ); $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId()); $finalPrice = $Customprice + $_product->getPrice(); $item->setCustomPrice($finalPrice); $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice); $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true); $item->save(); After that when customer as guest logged in and customer add to cart any of the product at that time display the error like: **"Cannot add the item to shopping cart"** How to fix this error?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/121168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it's not getting called in `config or bundle` item. Please try this code in your `observer.php`.

```
<?php
class Ucs_CatalogOrder_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter($observer) {
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
       $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }
    $walletAmount = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('card_wallet_amount');

    //not sure why calling $item->getOriginalPrice() not getting product's price
    //getting price from catalog model
    $productPrice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getFinalPrice();

    //adding custom with original price
    $finalPrice = (int)$walletAmount + (int)$productPrice;

    if($finalPrice > 0){
        $item->setCustomPrice($finalPrice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice);
        $item->setCardWalletAmount($finalPrice);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($finalPrice); 

}
```

Comment: This event can also insert the custom amount into the field `CardWalletAmount` added in sales_flat_quote_item table?

Comment: Where is your `CardWalletAmount` column? In which table?

Comment: its on sales_flat_quote_item, user can enter any amount on product detail page only, once user click on add to cart, then the amount should be updated. I think above event trigger on showing product detail page itself

Comment: I tried that too. Field card_wallet_amount get updated, but still in shopping cart only the product price is showing not the custom amount sum up with product amount

Comment: Your event is triggering when the product detail page is loaded, not the instant at adding the product into cart

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was not understanding your qst. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I am following the above in observer, it is updating custom_price, original_custom_price, but still in shopping cart only the base price is displaying.

Comment: This is what I am having in my question itself right? My problem is final price in cart page is not showing with the updated price

Comment: Check my updated answer, and can confirm it is working in my testing magento instance.

Comment: see my product price is $10 and I am adding $20 as a custom amount, then I click on add to cart, now on the cart page product price should be shown as $30, But my code updates the original_custom_price and custom_price successfully but on the cart page again it showing only the product price $10 only, am i clear now?

Comment: Can you confirm you have updated with last updated answer code? Because it is working in my end.

Comment: I am really very sorry to say, please refer my screenshots with my updated question

Comment: Can u enable my last add_success message code and also include full row of the database.

Comment: Find full row image here https://www.dropbox.com/s/yn39i67g5bsuwnt/full_row.png?dl=0 I added the add_success, I am not finding any changes

Comment: Using your answer, on cart page sub total is showing the sum of product price and custom variable value?

Comment: Yes, you can add **$walletPrice** in success message to check if you are getting customer input amount right. This will show on cart page message section.

Comment: Is it theme related? Are you using default theme or rwd theme?

Comment: my bad luck, nothing works :-( enabling Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($walletAmount);  is not showing any message in cart page

Comment: So that's the reason. You are not getting anything from post data. But I doubt it's not the case, since you said your walletammount table is getting the amount.

Comment: Are you refreshing the cart page or adding product. You should empty your cart and add product to get this effect.

Comment: Yes, upon changing in any file, I am clearing cache, emptying cart go to home page, then adding a new product, :-( should I change anything on view files?

Comment: if $walletAmount is empty then the custom_price and original_custom_price value should not also, update right?

Comment: Add how you adding input field in view page. I will check tomorrow. By the time debug why passing data to observer not working.

Comment: Sure. I will try as much as possible

Comment: Hi, just now noticed it.. this logic works for simple product, but not for configurable product